# How can I use query with RequestParam in Springboot?

Tags: java, jquery, sql, spring, spring-boot

I have this query in repository :

```
@Query("Select e FROM Employee e WHERE " +

            "e.startDate LIKE CONCAT('%',:date,'%')"+

           "And e.salary > LIKE CONCAT('%',:salary,'%')")
    List<Employee> searchEmployees(String query);
```

And this is my controller :

```
@GetMapping(path="/search")
   public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> searchEmployees(@RequestParam("date")String query){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.searchEmployees(query));
   }
```

I can't add second RequestParam to Controller. What is the concept when trying to add two RequestParam

Comment: Your query is wrong... You cannot use a LIKE on a date or number field. Nor should you use a `String` for this but proper dates and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this;

```
@GetMapping(path="/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> searchEmployees(@RequestParam("date") String query, 
                                                      @RequestParam("test") String test){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.searchEmployees(query));
}
```

Comment: So can I check startDate and salary with these query at same time?

Comment: Yes you can, just put your variable instead of test

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping(path="/search")
   public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> searchEmployees(@RequestParam("date")String date,@RequestParam("salary")String salary){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.searchEmployees(query));
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.